# Image not visible on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Am trying to use a sugar orm database to store image and text, but nothing is been displayed on the recylerview although am getting a confirmation that data is been stored in my database. This is the bit of code from my MainActivity.class that is saving value to the database, as well as to display the saved data to the recyclerview. But my problem is that its not showing anything when I run my code. Please help!

```
    recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    imagepojo = new ImageSugarPojo();
    int image = imagepojo.setImage(R.drawable.atama);
    String text = imagepojo.setText("Soup");
    imageSugar = new ArrayList<ImageSugarPojo>();
    imageSugar.add(new ImageSugarPojo( image,text));
    imagepojo.save();
    long count = ImageSugarPojo.count(ImageSugarPojo.class);
    Log.i("Count: ",String.valueOf(count));


    imageSugar = new ArrayList<ImageSugarPojo>();
    imageSugar = ImageSugarPojo.listAll(ImageSugarPojo.class);
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,imageSugar);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: post your adapter please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated your code since you said my first solution did not work for you.

This is the ImageSugarPojo class it is the same with yours

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class ImageSugarPojo extends SugarRecord{

private String image;
private String text;

public ImageSugarPojo(){}

public ImageSugarPojo(String image, String text){
    this.image =image;
    this.text = text;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    image = image;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

The ViewHolder class for the Adapter is like this

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public TextView categoryName;
public ImageView categoryImage;
public View mItemView;


public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mItemView = itemView;
    categoryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    categoryImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
}
}
```

In the adapter class, you can see that I stored the image and text as String since it is hard to store image resource id as int in Sugar ORM database.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;

public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private List<ImageSugarPojo> categoryObject;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<ImageSugarPojo> categoryObject) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryObject = categoryObject;
}

@Override
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_category_list, parent, false);
    return new CategoryViewHolder(layoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ImageSugarPojo catObject = categoryObject.get(position);
    holder.categoryName.setText(catObject.getText());
    int resId = getResourseId(context, "drawable", catObject.getImage(), context.getPackageName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryObject.size();
}

public static int getResourseId(Context context, String pVariableName, String pResourcename, String pPackageName) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(pVariableName, pResourcename, pPackageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error getting Resource ID.", e);
    }
}
}
```

The layout file for the adapter class is simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/sandals" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pizza"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageSugarPojo imagepojo = new ImageSugarPojo();
    imagepojo.setImage("sandals");
    imagepojo.setText("Soup");
    imagepojo.save();

    long count = ImageSugarPojo.count(ImageSugarPojo.class);
    Log.i("Count: ",String.valueOf(count));
    Log.i("Display: ",String.valueOf(imagepojo.getImage()));

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.category_menu);
    GridLayoutManager mGrid = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGrid);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    List<ImageSugarPojo> imageSugar = ImageSugarPojo.listAll(ImageSugarPojo.class);

    CategoryAdapter mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, imageSugar);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but its still not displaying anything on screen when I ran it, but its showing that something was saved in the database

Comment: did you get count equal 1 when you run the code? also add empty constructor in your ImageSugarPojo class.

Comment: my count 1 I/Count:: 1

Comment: public class ImageSugarPojo extends SugarRecord {
    int image;
    String text;

    public ImageSugarPojo(){}
    public ImageSugarPojo(int image, String text){
        this.image =image;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        image = image;

    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it worked out well. I appreciate the help

Comment: Is there a way I could save different images and display them?